# SQL Help: Complex query

Tags: sql

```
table : metrics
```

columns:

```
1. name : Name
2. instance: A name can have several instances 
(Name: John, Instances: John at work, John at concert)
3. metric: IQ, KQ, EQ
4. metric_value: Any numeric
```

Objective of the query

Find out the metrics whose `metric_value` is 0 for all instances for all names.

Nature of data

A name's metric '`M`' for instance '`X`' could be 10. But for the same name and the same metric instance  '`Y`' could be `0`. In this case, '`M`' should NOT be returned.

Edit:
Sample data:

```
NAME    INSTANCE    METRIC  VALUE
John    At work         IQ  0
John    At home         EQ  10
John    At a concert    KQ  0
Jim At work         IQ  0
Jim At home         KQ  0
Tina    At home         IQ  100
Tina    At work         EQ  0
Tina    At work         KQ  0
```

In this case, only KQ should be returned since it is always zero for all Names and their instances.

Comment: please post some sample data and your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT metric
  FROM metrics
 GROUP BY metric
HAVING SUM(metric_value) = 0
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0e3a5/1)** demo

**UPDATE** If metric_value can have negative values then use this one

```
SELECT metric
  FROM metrics
 GROUP BY metric
HAVING SUM(ABS(metric_value)) = 0
```

Here is updated **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0af51/4)** demo

Comment: Worked! Thanks. I unnecessarily complicated things in my mind.

Comment: Be aware that if one metric is -5 and another is 5 then this will incorrectly product a result.

Comment: You mean like Gordon Linoffs answer:) ? I argue that the only real answer based on the requirements is using NOT EXISTS. But this is probably just a lack of precision in the question. No big deal.

Answer (score 0):

A list based on your data:

```
SELECT name, metric FROM metrics GROUP BY name, metric HAVING SUM(metric_value) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this looks suspiciously like homework.... see if this gives you what you're after:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M1.Metric
FROM METRICS M1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM METRICS M2 
    WHERE M2.Metric <> 0
    AND M1.Metric = M2.Metric
)
```

Comment: THanks for the help..but I assure you this is not homework. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the other answers assume that `metric` is positive.  The OP says it can be *any* numeric.  Here are two methods for this to work.

Check on the sum of the absolute values:

```
SELECT metric
FROM metrics
GROUP BY metric
HAVING SUM(abs(metric_value)) = 0
```

Explicitly check that there are no non-zero values:

```
SELECT metric
FROM metrics
GROUP BY metric
HAVING SUM(case when metric_value <> 0 and metric_value is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```